# Using system() in a thread C++

Tags: c++, system-calls

I want to use the method system() in a (non-main) thread(pthread) in C++. For example,

```
system("/path/to/some/script.sh");
```

Is this permitted? If so, is it safe and are there any precautions I should take?

The reason I'm asking is that I've had the following comment from a code reviewer:

"The rule is system() can only be called from a single-threaded process. I think you need to move your new code to a separate application."

Is the first sentence of the comment valid?

Comment: First of all, for generating an RSA keypair, you'd be better off using `libssl` than hacking together a `system()` call to invoke `ssh-keygen`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of GNU/Linux implementation of `system`, it modifies the *process* signal mask during command execution. In multithreaded program, we're in for nasty surprises, e.g. if another thread `fork`s at the same time.

Comment: ^So, can I take your answer as 'One should avoid using system() in a multi-threaded program'?

Comment: Perhaps not so strong, like "avoiding system() for multi-threaded program is usually/frequently well-justified". If I *knew* there is no `fork`/`exec`, and `SIGINT`/`SIGQUIT`/`SIGCHLD` handlers & masks are unimportant -- I could take the risk of using `system`.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it for a wide variety of different reasons, the problem with signal masks just being one.

In general, `fork` and threads are a tricky mix and need to be handled with care. The existing library functions were likely not written with a multi-threaded program in mind.